# JS variable setting inside jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with setting variables for some opening and closing menus. I need to have a variable I can query as I have other click functions going on that will open and close different menus, so I can't use a toggle.

I don't understand why the following code does not work. Please could someone advise as I can't quite get it, I understand variable scope, but I think the way the jQuery does the click function is confusing me. Or perhaps there is a better pattern to follow for this kind of functionality..

```
var opentags = false;

$('a#tags').click(function () {

    if (opentags == true) {
            $('nav#tags').slideUp(); 
            // and other stuff
            var opentags = false;
    } else {
            $('nav#tags').slideDown();
            // and other other stuff 
            var opentags = true;
    }});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redeclaring a new local variable in the function because of the `var` keyword. Get rid of that.

Also, there's no reason to compare boolean variables to the boolean constants:

```
  if (opentags) {
    $('#tags').slideUp();
    opentags = false;
  }
  else {
    $('#tags').slideDown();
    opentags = true;
  }
```

Note also that you don't need the "nav" in the selectors; "id" values should be unique on the page anyway.

Using `var` is a really important thing in general, of course, so don't get the idea that it's a bad thing. It's just that in this case you *want* to access the variable declared outside the function scope.

Comment: I never used to use var to declare but recently started, now I fully understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`var opentags` creates a new local variable, which only lives inside that callback.
You want to set the existing global variable.